# Filtering record using two different date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I have this table **Tbl1**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl1]
(
    [Code] [nvarchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [Date1] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date2] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Code] ASC)
)
```

with the  following data:

| Code | Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OE1 | NULL | 2020-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
| OE2 | NULL | 2021-10-31 00:00:00.000 |
| TE1 | 2020-11-30 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-31 00:00:00.000 |
| TE2 | 2020-11-30 00:00:00.000 | 2020-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
| TE3 | 2020-11-30 00:00:00.000 | 2022-08-31 00:00:00.000 |

Let's say `Date1` is the date where an item is intentionally disposed while `Date2` is the actual or should be scrap date. Records should be filtered by these dates with the following scenario.

- **(A)** If my selected month is November 2020, only OE1 and OE2 should be display since TE1, TE2, TE3 are disposed on Nov. 2020.
- **(B)** If my selected month is less than or equal to October 2020, all codes should be display since October 2020 is less than the Date1 values and less than or equal to Date2 values.
- **(C)** If my selected month is December 2020, only OE1 and OE2 should be display.
- **(D)** If my selected month is January 2021, OE2 should be display since scrap date is 10/31/2021.

What I've tried is

```
SELECT * 
FROM Lapsing 
WHERE FORMAT(Date2, 'yyyyMM') >= 202011
AND FORMAT(ISNULL(DisposalDate, '1/1/1990'), 'yyyyMM') < 202011
```

but it only works for the first scenario (A).

Comment: One point first - you mention OE3 in your scenarios, but you don't have an OE3 record in your data sample.  Also OE2 has an October date but in your scenario C you say that OE2 should be part of the displayed results - is that correct?

Comment: Please show your expected results, and if you add your sample data as DDL+DML its **much** easier for us to assist you.

Comment: @Craig, OE3 is also the OE2. Apology for the typo. OE2 should be part of the scenario 3 because Date2 is 12/31/2021.

Comment: [edit] any additional information directly into the question. And I'm not asking for you to describe the results in words, I'm asking you to show us the exact results you expect. Data is worth 1000 words.

Comment: You certainly shouldn't compare dates as string... compare them as native dates - not only will they work as expected they will perform better. And to clarify, do you only ever select a month to run your query against?

Comment: And your logic isn't clear, it seems if the month is the same as Date1 you filter it out, but if its the same as Date2 you include it?

Comment: @DaleK, to clarify, selection is based on month and year. I just formatted it in yyyyMM. And, as mentioned, Date1 is a date where an item is intentionally disposed while Date2 is the actual scrapdate or life  of an item. If my selected month is November 2020, and if the code has date that falls in November 2020, even if its scrap date is greater than December 2020, that code will be filtered out.  That would be a case to case basis as shown in stated scenarios.

Comment: Still not clear, if you select "November 2020" you don't include TE1,2,3 because they are disposed of in November. But if you select "December 2020" you do include OE1 which has a scrap date in December. You exclude November, but include December - seems inconsistent?

Answer (score 0):

If you just use the ISNULL across your two date columns, then you should get the results that you expect.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Lapsing 
WHERE FORMAT(ISNULL(Date1, Date2), 'yyyyMM') > 202011;
--WHERE FORMAT(Date2, 'yyyyMM') >= 202011
--  AND FORMAT(ISNULL(DisposalDate, '1/1/1990'), 'yyyyMM') < 202011
```

I will say a couple of things, though:

1. I'm assuming that "Date2" cannot be Null - if it can then you'd have to have an addition to your where clause ... maybe OR ISNULL(Date1, Date2) Is Null - this would mean that a record would always be returned if it had neither a disposal date or an "expiry" date
2. I've kept your method of comparing the date (using FORMAT yyyyMM) ... it's probably not the way that I would ordinarily compare date columns, but each to their own

Comment: yes,DAte2 cannot be NULL. , Your query will display all record if the selected month is 202011. Its should not include codes with Date1 that falls in November 2020.

Comment: Oh, right the >= should just be >    Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

You always want to compare dates as dates in your `where` clause, both so that you know exactly what you are comparing and for performance reasons. When using the column without converting SQL Server can utilise an index (if it exists). But as soon as you transform it using a function it (usually) has to do an entire table scan.

I think its as simple as an `OR` condition as follows:

```
declare @CutoffDate date = '01 Nov 2020'; --'01 Oct 2020' --'01 Dec 2020' --'01 Jan 2021'

select *
from #Tbl1
where (Date1 is not null and Date1 >= dateadd(month, 1, @CutoffDate))
or (Date1 is null and Date2 >= @CutoffDate);
```

BTW: If you are only storing dates, I suggest using the `date` datatype rather than `datetime`.

Comment: As response to this and to your other comments above., it is because TE1,2,3 are already disposed on "November 2020" and they did not reach their actual scrap date. If we say generate list as of "November 2020", what is needed is to display list of items with Scrap Date (Date2) greater than or equal to "November 2020" but not yet dispose on or before thi date, whereas TE1,2,3 should not be belong because they were disposed on "November 2020".

If we say generate list as of "December 2020", TE1,2,3 still SHOULD NOT BE included in the list.

Comment: If we say genererate list as of "October 2020", TE1,2,3 SHOULD BE included in the list since their Scrap Dates (Date 2) is on "December 2020 and beyond"; AND NOT YET disposed on "November 2020".

Comment: @LadyA in that case my answer produces the desired results.